# Errors in Waksman's Solution to Cellular Automaton Firing Squad Problem?

Tags: reference-request, formal-languages, automata-theory, cellular-automata, computation

Recently, a student and I have been working through Waksman's paper *[``An Optimum Solution to the Firing Squad Synchronization Problem.'](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995866901100)*' The paper claims that for any value of $n$, the proposed cellular automaton will reach a synchronized state with all cells in the same state in time $t = 2n - 2$ steps.

We were surprised that for $n = 4$ (a general and three soldiers), our calculations gave this:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
P_0 & Q & Q & Q \\
P_0 & A_{010} & Q & Q \\
P_0 & B_0 & A_{011} & Q \\
P_0 & B_0 & Q & P_1 \\
P_0 & B_0 & Q & P_1
\end{array} $$
so that $(P_0, B_0, Q, P_1)$ is a fixed point and the soldiers never reach the synchronized ``all firing'' state promised in the paper. The student wrote a program to check, and it seems that there are many other values of $n$ for which the cells are not synchronized at time $t = 2n - 2$. We were wondering if anyone else had noticed or could verify this.

It's clear that there are some minor misprints in the tables ($\varphi$ instead of $\Phi$ for the wall state, and $\varphi$ instead of $\overline{\varphi}$ in the table for $P_0$). But this seems more fundamental ,and either we are simply mistaken in our calculations/understanding, or some other parts of the solution are not accurate. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: By doing an Internet search I find a snippet with author H. Umeo and mentioning errors, presumably of Waksmans paper. You might try finding and reading that paper.  Gerhard "Use A Citation Search Also" Paseman, 2018.05.11.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gerhard Paseman's comment, I found the paper [*Correction, Optimization and Verification of Transition Rule Set for Waksman's Firing Squad Synchronization Algorithm*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4471-0709-5_18) by Umeo, Sogabe, and Nomura. Also relevant is [*A Survey on Optimum-Time Firing Squad Synchronization Algorithms for One-Dimensional Cellular Automata*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/79e1/efba6e44edc1a0ae2ef915e0b1dfcbd6d90d.pdf) by Umeo, Hisaoka, and Sogabe.